# Add condition to entity field query to filter field collection item by host entity

Tags: 7

I have a field collection, `field_speaker` with a field `field_speaker_user_reference` (User entity reference).

I would like to know if a specific user is referenced on a specific node.  I have the following which will return 0 results:

```
$efq = new EntityFieldQuery();
$efq->entityCondition('entity_type', 'field_collection_item');
$efq->propertyCondition('field_name', 'field_speaker');
$efq->entityCondition('entity_id', $node->nid);
$efq->fieldCondition('field_speaker_user_reference', 'target_id', $user->uid);
$results = $efq->execute();
```

The table `drupal_field_data_field_speaker` has `entity_id`, which is the host entity (it's a node id).  The table `drupal_field_data_field_speaker_user_reference` has the user referenced.  If I remove `$efq->entityCondition('entity_id', $node->nid);` I get all items for user.

A sql query that gets the results I want would be:

```
select * from 
  drupal_field_data_field_speaker s
  JOIN drupal_field_data_field_speaker_user_reference u 
  ON u.entity_id = s.field_speaker_value
  AND u.field_speaker_user_reference_target_id = 26308 
  AND s.entity_id = 47746
```

What is the right condition to add to entity field query so that I can filter by the host entity?

Comment: What happens if you remove `$efq->fieldCondition('field_speaker_user_reference', 'target_id', $user->uid);` do you get all items with node 47746?

Comment: I'm having this exact problem - did you get to the bottom of it?